# Skip element while converting Enum to List

Tags: python, enums, python-3.6

I have following class defined:

```
class MyEnum(IntEnum):
    NONE=-1
    A=0
    B=1
    C=2
```

So the result of `list(MyEnum)` is obviously `[<MyEnum.NONE: -1>, <MyEnum.A: 0>, <MyEnum.B: 1>, <MyEnum.C: 2>]`.

Is there any method I can implement in `MyEnum` so the result of `list(MyEnum)` will be `[<MyEnum.A: 0>, <MyEnum.B: 1>, <MyEnum.C: 2>]`

Comment: A simple workaround is to have a `MyEnum.tolist()` function that returns the list

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing you can add in `MyEnum` itself to alter what `list()` will return.

As @PranavHosangadi said, you can add a method (or any descriptor, such as [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)), that will do what need:

```
class MyEnum(IntEnum):
    NONE=-1
    A=0
    B=1
    C=2
    #
    @classmethod
    def valid_choices(cls):
        choices = list(cls)
        choices.remove(cls.NONE)
        return choices
```

In use:

```
>>> MyEnum.valid_choices()
[<MyEnum.A: 0>, <MyEnum.B: 1>, <MyEnum.C: 2>]
```